# Eyefinity Setup on Z68 board with LucidLogix Virtu and i7 2600k

Tags: intel-core-i7, eyefinity

I have set up Eyefinity 3 monitor on an i7-870 with a ATI 5770 in the past as part of a display and am planning a new system for the near future.

I have a i7-2600k processor and am leaning heavily towards the Asus P8Z68 Deluxe motherboard, with one of the main considerations being the LucidLogix Virtu technology, and being able to use both Quick Sync and a discrete card for Eyefinity.

I know that this configuration is supposed to work fairly well and the setup should be straight forward.

Can anyone advise what sort of performance can be expected compared with running the discrete card flat out?  (Ie has anyone got this setup and run some benchmarks?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this review](http://www.hardwareheaven.com/reviews/1196/pg12/intel-socket-1155-roundup-june-2011-h67p67-and-z68-lucid-virtu.html), which is current, that suggests that using the virtu technology in D mode did not provide any performance gain from the Intel GPU, and introduced a lot of potential driver issues.  They didn't note a performance loss in D mode, though there was a dramatic one in I mode (no surprise there).

If I don't find more direct evidence to support the Intel Quick Sync performance gain, I may personally opt for a p67.

I hope this helps someone else! :)

Answer (score 1):

Non technical answer:

I am looking for info on compatability of using Eyefinity and Lucidlogic Virtu. But I do have VIRTUE running on an i5 sandybridge z68 MOB.

I haven't hooked uo my 3 monitors yet. I'm waiting on a cable to be delivered.

But in case you don't know, if you use the discreet PCi-e GPU to attach a monitor,or monitors, you can, through the hidden taskbar menu, enable or disable the LucidVirtue software. When the Virtu window appears, there is a big button to do this, with immmediate implementation.

So you can in seconds, by-pass the Virtu software and have your 100% pure GPU's power.
If you hook up the monitor to the Sandy Bridge CPU's onboard HDMI, this doesn't work of course, because if you bypass the Virtu software, you are not hooked to your 3rd party GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware Canucks has a well done [article benchmarking the Z68](http://www.hardwarecanucks.com/forum/hardware-canucks-reviews/43205-intel-z68-review-sandy-bridge-platform-expands-6.html) platform and the GPU switching.  It includes general system performance, in-game benchmarks, as well as power consumption statistics.

Comment: I had read this article, however, since the publication date was May 11 I thought that more current information might be available.  For example the issue about having the bios set to the igpu is no longer current, it's been fixed to run with either the igpu or the dgpu as a primary.

Comment: I re-read the article and also note that it does not make any mention of Eyefinity setups in conjunction with Virtu (probably since it isn't possible to setup Eyefinity in a igpu-centric configuration)